# Is it OK to just use POST method and JSON format for a REST-like API in Scala/Play

Tags: json, scala, rest, playframework

We decided to use POST method and JSON format for all of our internal APIs which makes everything simpler. But then we realized that this is not truly RESTful. More over it seems that GET requests are more lightweight than POSTs under high load.

We have a problem regarding GET methods. We have to bind our criteria object to the HTTP request (query string) which forces us to build [Form](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaForms) object for each criteria model. As you know building the Form object will be done manually and there is no automation available like what we have for JSON formatters ([Macro Inception](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonInception)).

Another issue is that we have to decide on whether to use route parameters or querystring.

I think it's simpler to use a single HTTP method and make all API calls uniform. Does it make sense?

Comment: "Another issue is that we have to decide on whether to use route parameters or querystring" - query strings are good "additional" parameters for making conditions, example : /persons/{name}?order={orderParam}&firstCapitalized={capitalized}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POST is the method to be used for any operation that isn't standardized by the HTTP protocol, and simple retrieval is standardized in the GET method. So, using POST for simple retrieval isn't RESTful. More than that, it seems like you want to use POST so you can treat querystring parameters in the same way as the POST payload, but REST URIs are atomic identifiers, including the querystring. Your application shouldn't rely on URI semantics, and extracting bits of information that serve any purpose other than identification also doesn't make much sense in REST.

Frankly, from what you describe your API is so far from being considered truly RESTful that this shouldn't be a concern at all. Do whatever is more consistent with your tools and works better for your application. REST isn't for everyone, and worrying about designing an API that's truly RESTful when that isn't a requirement for your application is more likely to lead to bad design choices.

Comment: It's funny to me how two people can read the same question and come away with two totally different ideas of what the OP is describing. Smells like a poorly worded question. Your answer, however, is spot on.

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with using `POST` like you're describing. In fact, `GET` requests should not alter the state of the server but instead should only be used for retrieval. In other words, if you're sending data to the server to, for instance, create an entity, using GET would be technically incorrect.

There's nothing you're describing that sounds "not RESTful." `POST` can definitely be part of a RESTful architecture.

That said, the HTTP method you use should correspond to the action it will perform. For example, if you're retrieving an entity by ID, you should use `GET` whereas if you're updating an entity by ID, you should use `POST` or `PUT`. This gives developers using the API a hint as to the side effects and intended usage of the various API methods.